# OpenCL Kernel Increment returning wrong value, why?

Tags: kernel, opencl, increment

I was trying to increment value of some value in a global buffer. Let me give you the skeleton.

```
__kernel void relax_a_point(__global float* pivot_indices)
{
        int gid = get_global_id(0);
        pivot_indices[gid * 8 + 2] = pivot_indices[gid * 8 + 2] + 1.f;
}
```

In stead of increasing the value by 1, it increases the value by 1024/1023/1022. If I add 0.f, the value remains intact. Any idea why this is happening? Any other change to any elements of pivot_indices (swapping etc) results in wrong output.

pivot_indices buffer was created using CL_MEM_READ_WRITE flag.

Comment: try adding gid to that value instead of 1.f. to check if kernel executed on 2D thread array with  something like [1,1024,1] ndrange setting

Comment: I was launching 2D kernel with local size 16x16, global size 1024x1024. Once I switched back to 1D kernel launch with local size 1 and global size 1024, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you are using 2D kernel with sizes 1024x1024, but in:

```
int gid = get_global_id(0);
```

the work item id is just based on the global dimension 0. Which means, 1024 work items share the same `gid`.

The 1024/1023/1022 random results are simple data access races between work items, because there is no synchronization between them. Leading to some additions being lost in the race process.

You should do this instead:

```
__kernel void relax_a_point(__global float* pivot_indices)
{
        int gid = get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1)*get_global_size(0);
        pivot_indices[gid * 8 + 2] = pivot_indices[gid * 8 + 2] + 1.f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks DarkZeros. This is the case. Since I am new in GPU programming, I was not paying attention to the work items organization.